# PyGame - Camera doesn't move on key press

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to get the camera to move, but it's not having any effect when I click q w e a s or d. I tried asking the original programmer, but that came to nought, so I don't know what to do.

Code:

```
import pygame, sys, math

class Cam:
    def __init__(self,pos=(0,0,0),rot=(0,0)):
        self.pos = list(pos)
        self.rot = list(rot)

    def update(self,dt,key):
        s = dt*10

        if key[pygame.K_q]: self.pos[1]-=s
        if key[pygame.K_e]: self.pos[1]+=s

        if key[pygame.K_w]: self.pos[2]+=s
        if key[pygame.K_s]: self.pos[2]-=s
        if key[pygame.K_a]: self.pos[0]-=s
        if key[pygame.K_d]: self.pos[0]+=s

pygame.init()
w,h = 400,400; cx,cy = w//2,h//2
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

verts = (-1,-1,-1,),(1,-1,-1),(1,1,-1),(-1,1,-1),(-1,-1,1),(1,-1,1),(1,1,1),(-1,1,1)
edges = (0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,0),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,4),(0,4),(1,5),(2,6),(3,7)

cam = Cam((0,0,-5))

while True:
    dt = clock.tick()/1000

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit(); sys.exit()

    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    for edge in edges:

        points = []
        for x,y,z in (verts[edge[0]],verts[edge[1]]):

            x-=cam.pos[0]
            y-=cam.pos[1]
            z-=cam.pos[2]

            f = 200/z
            x,y = x*f,y*f
            points+=[(cx+int(x),cy+int(y))]
    pygame.draw.line(screen,(0,0,0),points[0],points[1],1)


    pygame.display.flip()

key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
cam.update(dt,key)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to properly indent the last two lines.

```
import pygame, sys, math

class Cam:
    def __init__(self,pos=(0,0,0),rot=(0,0)):
        self.pos = list(pos)
        self.rot = list(rot)

    def update(self,dt,key):
        s = dt*10

        if key[pygame.K_q]: self.pos[1]-=s
        if key[pygame.K_e]: self.pos[1]+=s

        if key[pygame.K_w]: self.pos[2]+=s
        if key[pygame.K_s]: self.pos[2]-=s
        if key[pygame.K_a]: self.pos[0]-=s
        if key[pygame.K_d]: self.pos[0]+=s

pygame.init()
w,h = 400,400; cx,cy = w//2,h//2
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

verts = (-1,-1,-1,),(1,-1,-1),(1,1,-1),(-1,1,-1),(-1,-1,1),(1,-1,1),(1,1,1),(-1,1,1)
edges = (0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,0),(4,5),(5,6),(6,7),(7,4),(0,4),(1,5),(2,6),(3,7)

cam = Cam((0,0,-5))

while True:
    dt = clock.tick()/1000

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit(); sys.exit()

    screen.fill((255,255,255))

    for edge in edges:

        points = []
        for x,y,z in (verts[edge[0]],verts[edge[1]]):

            x-=cam.pos[0]
            y-=cam.pos[1]
            z-=cam.pos[2]

            f = 200/z
            x,y = x*f,y*f
            points+=[(cx+int(x),cy+int(y))]
    pygame.draw.line(screen,(0,0,0),points[0],points[1],1)


    pygame.display.flip()

    # these two lines should be inside the `while` loop
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    cam.update(dt,key)
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean, @pol002? What did you expect, and what did you get? What debugging have you done? Have you printed out any intermediate values to understand what your code is doing?